# MySQL Query: UPDATE and/or APPEND

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a temporary table that I use to insert into the master db.

The temp table is named "temp_table"
The master table is "master"

I currently use the following command to update "master"

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master;
SHOW COLUMNS FROM master;
INSERT INTO master
SELECT * FROM temp_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email = VALUES(email), phone = VALUES(phone)
```

Now, I want to be able to append field (counter) from the "temp table" into "master."  The field already exists in both tables and I just want to be able to update or append it.

"counter" field in master may be empty or it may contain a number value already.

```
In cases where the value exists, it should append separated by a comma.  Format (88,89,90)
In cases where the it's empty, it should update (88)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you call append is also an update. However, you really should think twice before storing a delimited list of values in a single field value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad for details why this is not such a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
on duplicate key update 
    email = values(email), 
    phone = values(phone),
    counter = case when counter is null 
        then values(counter) 
        else concat(counter, ',', values(counter))
    end
```

You can also phrase this with `coalesce()`, although the expression might be a bit more complicated to understand:

```
on duplicate key update 
    email = values(email), 
    phone = values(phone),
    counter = concat(
        coalesce(concat(counter, ','), ''),
        values(counter)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is nice and clear.   I ran it and i'm getting ambiguous error with "counter" field.